# React router v4 parameter going as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a route config like this:
`/${URL.PRODUCT}/:category/:brand/:flavour/`, with `exact={true}` and it loads the Product component.

On Product component I have this:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selectedCategory: props.match.params.category || '',
        selectedFlavour: props.match.params.flavour || '',
        selectedBrand: props.match.params.brand || '',
    }
    s("PARAMS", JSON.stringify(props.match.params)); //console on server
    c("PARAMS", JSON.stringify(props.match.params)); // console on browser
}
```

Now, on some other component I have a click event, which does this:

```
clickHandler = (cardData) => {
        let path = `/${URL.PRODUCT}/${cardData.selectedCategory}/${cardData.selectedCard}/${cardData.slug}`;
        cardData.type === CONTENT_TYPE.FLAVOUR && !!cardData.slug && this.props.history.push(path);
    }
```

And `cardData` looks like this:

```
{
    id: 3
    image: "/some/imagepath/"
    name: "Diet Coke"
    selectedCard: "cocacola"
    selectedCategory: "softdrinnk"
    slug: "dietcoke"
    type: "flavour"
}
```

Its resulting in something like this: `/product/softdrinnk/cocacola/dietcoke`

Now the problem: As I am hitting `this.props.history.push()` its making a server call (which it should not) also, with a wrong URL: `/product/softdrinnk/cocacola/undefined`

This is what my console looks like on client:

`PARAMS {"category":"softdrinnk","brand":"cocacola","flavour":"dietcoke"}`

And this is what I receive on server:

`PARAMS {"category":"softdrinnk","brand":"cocacola","flavour":"undefined"}`

I have spend the whole day figuring out why this behaviour is happening.

**Update:**

Even if when I hardcoded the URL: `/${URL.PRODUCT}/${cardData.selectedCategory}/${cardData.selectedCard}/dietcoke`, Its ignoring the last parameter and still and passing `undefined` to the server

And when I hit browser refresh on this route, it works normally and loads all the data

Comment: What does `cardData` look like? You have `selectedCategory`, `selectedFlavour`, `selectedBrand` in state, but only `selectedCategory` of those in `cardData`?

Comment: @Tholle updated that in my question

Comment: Thanks. Is your click handler on a button inside a form? You might have to do `clickHandler = (event, cardData) => { event.preventDefault(); ... }` if that's the case.

Comment: That's not in a form, its just another component with an `onCLick` event